# Differences between silver jewelry alloys

Tags: jewelry, metal

I have bought 2 necklaces from the same place.

The necklace on the left is 3mm width, has a dark metal color similar to that of stainless steel and tarnishes in a matter of days on me.

The necklase on the right is 2mm width, is very light, bright color and tarnishes in a matter of years on me.

Both of the chains are marked 925.

Is there any reason the wider and bigger necklace would be made from a different type of silver alloy as I see it very commonly used in bigger pieces of jewelry or was I just fooled by the seller?

[image: different silver alloy necklaces]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stainless steel ( assuming 316 ) is more corrosion resistant than silver and would not darken in air. Silver darkens with exposure to hydrogen sulfide ; yes I know there is "no" H2S around the home. However some smell from eggs is a ppb ( part per billion = not very much)  of H2S , and most of that and sewer gas H2S finds and reacts with any silver turning it dark. Most have experienced putting silver in a drawer or box and finding years later that it has darkened ( from sulfide). 92.5  % is the minimum silver content to be called sterling silver, so presumably both items are silver, the balance is primarily copper,  but may have a little nickel or zinc. My guess is that the brighter piece has a plating like rhodium to prevent the usual darkening of silver. But the real answer is that a jeweler would need to examine it.

Comment: One thing I would point out to @Deadfish is that Rhodium plating does make silver items a little dull in comparison to unplated silver in my experience. Was it sold cheaply?  My wife who makes silver jewellery questions the validity of the 925 hallmark on the tarnished necklace due to tarnishing very quickly and suggests getting it tested.